Toilet refill tube not filling tank
I am dealing with a Gerber toilet with a Fluidmaster 300 float.

When the refill tube is inserted “correctly” into the overflow tube, the tank does not fill with water.

The tank only fills when the refill tube is NOT inserted into the overflow tube, but is hanging over the tank.

After the water stops filling because the float is lifted, the tank then leaks water (I assume down the drain) slightly and water again comes out of the refill tube.

And the process repeats itself.

I have tried to remove and replace the flapper but it doesn’t seem to removable, as if it is part of the larger piece including the overflow tube.


Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Richard
NYC

please add a picture of the area that you are talking about

Fill valves are cheap and relatively easy to replace, so consider that instead of fiddling with the one you have. Water to fill the tank usually comes from another opening in the fill valve. The tube is just for the overflow (to rinse around the rim, etc depending on the porcelain you have.)
